# How to make phpStorm show all possibilities in CSS class completion with Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, phpstorm

I'm having trouble with auto-completion in phpStorm when it comes to Bootstrap. I'm using phpStorm 6. The problem is that it does not show all possible completions. It does show some.

For example:

[image: This is supposed to show table-strpied and table-hover]

This is supposed to show `table-strpied` and `table-hover` among other things, but it does not.

Is there a setting that I can use to solve this problem, or is this bug that is not solved or is this a feature waiting to be requested?

To assuage any suspicion on my part, a `.table-striped` is present in the bootstrap.css file:
[image: Just to be sure]

Comment: I am having this issue today in Web Storm 9 RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the known issue - please, vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5